# FuelPhp Relation Query as single result

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, fuelphp

When I do a Model_[Table name]::query()->relation([Other table]) query with FuelPHP, I get:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "[foreign_key"]: {
        "1": {[Other table row]},
    }
}
```

Is there a way to just get the data as:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    {[Other table row]},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, there's not.

Depending on your use case the EAV container might be useful or you can override the `to_array()` method in the model to provide the data in the format that you require.